# How do I get the word-embedding matrix from ft_word2vec (sparklyr-package)?

Tags: word2vec, sparklyr

I have another question in the word2vec universe.
I am using the 'sparklyr'-package. Within this package I call the ft_word2vec() function. I have some trouble understanding the output:
For each number of sentences/paragraphs I am providing to the ft_word2vec() function, I always get the same amount of vectors. Even, if I have more sentences/paragraphs than words. For me, that looks like I get the paragraph-vectors. Maybe a Code-example helps to understand my problem?

```
# add your spark_connection here as 'spark_connection = '

# create example data frame
FK_data = data.frame(sentences = c("This is my first sentence",
  "It is followed by the second sentence",
  "At the end there is the last sentence"))

# move the data to spark
sc_FK_data <- copy_to(spark_connection, FK_data, name = "FK_data", overwrite = TRUE)

# prepare data for ft_word2vec (sentences have to be tokenized [=list of words instead of one string in each row])
sc_FK_data <- ft_tokenizer(sc_FK_data, input_col = "icd_long", output_col = "tokens")

# split data into test and trainings sets
partitions <- sc_FK_data %>%
  sdf_random_split(training = 0.7, test = 0.3, seed = 123456) 
FK_train <- partitions$training
FK_test <- partitions$test

# given a trainings data set (FK_train) with a column "tokens" (for each row = a list of strings)
mymodel = ft_word2vec(
  FK_train,
  input_col = "tokens",
  output_col = "word2vec",
  vector_size = 15,
  min_count = 1,
  max_sentence_length = 4444,
  num_partitions = 1,
  step_size = 0.1,
  max_iter = 10,
  seed = 123456,
  uid = random_string("word2vec_"))

# I tried to get the data from spark with:
myemb = mymodel %>% sparklyr::collect()
```

Has somebody had similar experiences? Can someone explain what exactly the ft_word2vec() function returns? Do you have an example on how to get the word embedding vectors with this function? Or does the returned column indeed contain the paragraph vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my colleague found a solution! If you know how to do it, the instructions really begin to make sense!

```
# add your spark_connection here as 'spark_connection = '

# create example data frame
FK_data = data.frame(sentences = c("This is my first sentence",
  "It is followed by the second sentence",
  "At the end there is the last sentence"))

# move the data to spark
sc_FK_data <- copy_to(spark_connection, FK_data, name = "FK_data", overwrite = TRUE)

# prepare data for ft_word2vec (sentences have to be tokenized [=list of words instead of one string in each row])
sc_FK_data <- ft_tokenizer(sc_FK_data, input_col = "icd_long", output_col = "tokens")

# split data into test and trainings sets
partitions <- sc_FK_data %>%
  sdf_random_split(training = 0.7, test = 0.3, seed = 123456) 
FK_train <- partitions$training
FK_test <- partitions$test

# CHANGES FOLLOW HERE:
# We have to use the spark connection instead of the data. For me this was the confusing part, since i thought no data -> no model.
# maybe we can think of this step as an initialization
mymodel = ft_word2vec(
  spark_connection,
  input_col = "tokens",
  output_col = "word2vec",
  vector_size = 15,
  min_count = 1,
  max_sentence_length = 4444,
  num_partitions = 1,
  step_size = 0.1,
  max_iter = 10,
  seed = 123456,
  uid = random_string("word2vec_"))

# now that we have our model initialized, we add the word-embeddings to the model
w2v_model = ml_fit(w2v_model, sc_FK_EMB)

# now we can collect the embedding vectors
emb = word2vecmodel$vectors %>% collect()
```

Comment: what is sc_FK_EMB?